# Python Tkinter listbox input from txt file multiple lines are showing in one line

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, txt

My question is simple. I am saving my listbox into txt file according to below code:

```py
def file_save():
    global filename
    if filename == '':
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    if filename is not None:
        for i in textentry.get(0,END):
            filename.write(i+"\n")
```

My list box contains multiple lines like

```
aa
bb
cc
```

And my txt output is like that also.

But when I load this txt file into my empty listbox. It shows

```
aabbcc
```

My loading code is below:

```py
def file_open():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r+', filetypes =[('Txt', '*.txt')])
    if filename is not None:
        t = filename.read()
        textentry.delete(0, 'end')
        for item in t:
            textentry.insert(END, item)
        #textentry.insert(END, t)
        textentry.focus()
```

I tried adding `for item in t:` and it shows

```
a
a
b
...
```

`textentry.insert(END, t)` shows aabbcc

I need to show my loaded txt file as

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines` instead of `read`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Listbox, Tk

top = Tk()
textentry = Listbox(top)

filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r+', filetypes =[('Txt', '*.txt')])
if filename is not None:
    t = filename.readlines()
    textentry.delete(0, 'end')
    for item in t:
        textentry.insert('end', item)
    textentry.focus()

textentry.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Or you can use `t = filename.read().split("\n")`